# How to pick one non null date from dates - if date is null pick next one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to pick one date from week, it has to be Friday. However, when Friday is null - it means no data was entered, and I have to find any other day with data in the same week. Can someone share their views on how to solve this type of situation?

If you see in the following data, in the 2nd week, Friday has null entry, so another day has to be picked up.

```
Day Weekdate    Data entry dt   Data
1   2/7/2016        
2   2/8/2016        
3   2/9/2016        
4   2/10/2016       
5   2/11/2016       
6   2/12/2016   2/12/2016   500
7   2/13/2016       
1   2/14/2016       
2   2/15/2016       
3   2/16/2016       
4   2/17/2016   2/17/2016   300
5   2/18/2016       
6   2/19/2016   NULL    NULL
7   2/20/2016       
1   2/21/2016       
2   2/22/2016       
3   2/23/2016       
4   2/24/2016       
5   2/25/2016       
6   2/26/2016   2/26/2016   250
7   2/27/2016
```

Comment: What is the desired output from your sample data? Is there a preference to the order of days you want within a given week?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
--Not null data
select * from tblData
  where DATEPART(dw,weekDate) = 6 and data is not null

Union

Select data.* from 
  (
    select weekDate 
      from tblData
      where DATEPART(dw,weekDate) = 6 and data is null
  ) nullData --Select Friday with null data
  Cross Apply 
  (
    --Find first record with not null data that is within this week
    Select top 1 * 
      From tblData data
      Where
        data.weekDate between Dateadd(day, -6, nullData.weekDate) and nullData.weekDate
        and data.data is not null
      Order by data.weekDate desc
  ) data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to get the data entered for the latest date (Friday first, then every other day) for each week in your table:

```
SELECT
    Weeks.FirstofWeek,
    Detail.Day,
    Detail.DataEntryDt,
    Detail.Data
FROM
( --master list of weeks
    SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY,(1-DATEPART(dw,Weekdate)),Weekdate) AS FirstofWeek
    FROM dataTable
) AS Weeks
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( --detail
    SELECT 
        --order first by presence of data, then by date, selecting Friday first:
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(DAY,(1-DATEPART(dw,Weekdate)),Weekdate) ORDER BY CASE WHEN Data IS NOT NULL THEN 99 ELSE 0 END DESC, CASE WHEN [Day] = 6 THEN 99 ELSE [Day] END DESC) AS RowNum,
        [Day],
        DATEADD(DAY,(1-DATEPART(dw,Weekdate)),Weekdate) AS FirstofWeek,
        Weekdate,
        DataEntryDt,
        Data
    FROM dataTable 
) AS Detail
    ON Weeks.FirstofWeek = Detail.FirstofWeek
    AND Detail.RowNum = 1 --get only top record for week with data present
```